# How to add Javascript split message to a specific position in a Json file - DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I split the content of a message received on Discord into a specific channel and I would like to add it in an array of my JSON file which already contains elements. Do you have any ideas ?

```
client.on("message", (message) =>{
    if(message.channel.name === role_list.channel && message.content.includes("!addRole")) {
        let splitMessage=message.content.split(" ");
        let secondElement=splitMessage[1];
        let thirdElement=splitMessage[2];
        let obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(role_list));
        obj['reactions'].push(JSON.stringify(secondElement));
      //  role_list = JSON.stringify(obj);
    }
});
```

And here is the content of the JSON file:

```
{
  "message": "*ID Message*",
  "content": "*Message Content*",
  "channel": "*Name Channel*",
  "reactions": [
    {
      "role": "Greek",
      "emoji": ""
    },
    { 
      "role": "German",
      "emoji": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `<Property> = <Content>` so it would look like this `array[0].content = <Message>.content`, something like that, but you get the point, this will change the value, if that is what you want, with the same method you can add another property to that JSON, `<JSON>.newProperty = <Value>`

Comment: Thank you but I dont really understand what I can do

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result :

```
role_list['reactions'].push({role: secondElement, emoji: thirdElement});
            json=JSON.stringify(role_list);
            fs.writeFile('roles.json', json, (err) => {
                if(err)
                    console.log(err);
                else {
                    console.log("Nouveau rôle ajouté\n");

                    //Ajouter la reaction au message
                }
            });
```